# How to use NSTextView as a log console from a thread?

Tags: cocoa, nstextview

I am running another processing thread, and I would like to log results to a **NSTextView**, that when a new line is posted, it updates the view and positions the scrollbar to the bottom.
Any suggestions?

```
- (void)runProc
{
    do {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
        [self reportInfo:@"tick"];
    } while (stop == NO);    
}

- (void)report:(NSString*)string;
{
    [[consoleView textStorage] beginEditing];
    [[[consoleView textStorage] mutableString] appendString:string];
    [[[consoleView textStorage] mutableString] appendString:@"\n"];
    [[consoleView textStorage] endEditing];

    NSRange range;
    range = NSMakeRange ([[consoleView string] length], 0);

    [consoleView scrollRangeToVisible: range];
}
```

It gets to about 50 entries then locks the whole thing up.

Comment: also tried wrapping it in @synchronize but no luck, same lockup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of AppKit is not thread safe, you can't update an `NSTextView` from a secondary thread. All UI updates must be done on the main thread.

You need to call your reporting method like this:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(report:) withObject:@"tick" waitUntilDone:YES];
```